# How can I get the output of ls

Tags: minix

How can I get the output of ls? I want to add a indirection operator =>, and it's function is same as >, it means in the command line $ls => Files, the list of files in the directory is stored in the file Files

Answer (score 0):

Output redirection (and all other redirection for that matter) is a facility provided by the shell, not by the `ls` program. The `ls` just writes its output to standard output and, if the shell has redirected that to a file, that's where it goes.

So, if you want to add a `=>` token, it's the *shell* that you're going to have to modify, recompile and install. That's not necessarily an easy task, I've made changes to `bash` in the past and, while it's relatively easy to tinker around the edges (I added an internal command for outputting the `PS1` result string), I suspect redirection may be a little more difficult.

Still, it *may* be a matter of simply creating a new token `=>` and copying the code that's currently executed for `>`. It may also be that `ash`, the Minix3 shell, is a lot cleaner than `bash`. My advice would be to investigate `ash`, specifically the version found in Minix3, and just have a play.